# Unable to call constructor of friend class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, private, friend

I am trying to call my SocketConnection constructor from inside the definition of the node class, but I'm failing to understand the compile error I'm getting - I fail to see why the compiler thinks the constructor I declared for SocketConnection is not a constructor.

Here are the main parts of .h file code:

```
class Node
{
    public:
    Node() ; 
    int OnStart() ; 
    friend class SocketConnection ; 
} ; 

class SocketConnection
{
    public:
    Node * m_nptr ; 
    int m_sockfd ; 
    SocketConnection(Node * nptr) ; 
};
```

Here are the main parts of .cpp file:

```
int Node::OnStart()
{
    SocketConnection newConnection(this) ; 
    return 0 ; 
}

SocketConnection::SocketConection(Node * nptr): m_nptr(nptr)
{

}
```

On compilation, I get:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘SocketConection’ with no type
error: no ‘int SocketConnection::SocketConection(Node*)’ member function declared in class ‘SocketConnection’
In member function ‘int SocketConnection::SocketConection(Node*)’:
error: only constructors take base initializers
```

Can someone help me understand this ?

Cheers,
N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
SocketConnection::SocketConection(Node * nptr): m_nptr(nptr)
//                        ^
```

Change it into:

```
SocketConnection::SocketConnection(Node * nptr): m_nptr(nptr)
//                        ^^
```

Comment: Thanks Andy ! Wasn't using an IDE and didn't pay attention to that.